# setting temperature in Open Llama does not work

Tags: large-language-model

I try to generate several alternative continuations of given prompt with Open Llama, setting nonzero temperature:

```
import re
import torch
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM

model_path = 'openlm-research/open_llama_3b_v2'

tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, torch_dtype=torch.float16, device_map='auto')
text  = 'Once upon a time '
text_tokenized_for_llm = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
for i in range(25):
  result = model.generate(input_ids=text_tokenized_for_llm, max_new_tokens=6, temperature=2)
  text = tokenizer.decode(result[0])
  print('->' + text + '<-')
```

However, when I run the program, all continuations are the same:

```
-><s>Once upon a time 100 years ago,<-
-><s>Once upon a time 100 years ago,<-
-><s>Once upon a time 100 years ago,<-
(...)
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

## Investigations

It seems to me that you just always use `temperature=2` instead of `temperature=i`.

However, even when using `temperature=i` in your code, the temperature will not be applied. The temperature only has any effect if you foward inputs to the model in sampling mode. This can be achieved by passing another parameter `do_sample=True` to the models `generate(...)` function.

In your specific case you could just add this parameter like `result = model.generate(input_ids=text_tokenized_for_llm, max_new_tokens=6, do_sample=True, temperature=i)`.

Moreover, if you want to avoid the raise of `ValueError: 'temperature' has to be a strictly positive float, but is 2` as well as `ValueError: 'temperature' has to be a strictly positive float, but is 0.0`, you have to make sure that you are only passing positive non-zero `float` values. This can be achieved by adapting your `for` instruction to `for i in range(1, 25):` and by adapting the parameter pass in `generate(...)` to `model.generate(input_ids=input_ids, max_new_tokens=6, do_sample=True, temperature=float(i))`.

## Possible Solution

So if you use a code similar to the one below, everything should work as expected. Note that I used the model `meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf` instead, for which you will need to request access from Meta. However, the behaviour is the same for all `transformers` LLMs.

### Code

```
import os
import torch
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM
from dotenv import load_dotenv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv()

    llm = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf"
    huggingfacehub_api_key = os.getenv("HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY")

    tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(llm, token=huggingfacehub_api_key)
    model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(llm, token=huggingfacehub_api_key, device_map="auto",
                                             torch_dtype=torch.float16)
    text = "Once upon a time "
    input_ids = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

    for i in range(1, 25):
        result = model.generate(input_ids=input_ids, max_new_tokens=6, do_sample=True, temperature=float(i))
        text = tokenizer.decode(result[0])
        print(text)
        print("===============================================")
```

### Output

```
$ python test.py
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:02<00:00,  1.41s/it]
<s>Once upon a time 5 years ago, a tiny
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 3d printer in space.
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time � more exactly March and this
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time ........when Â a family
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time icy monstrums known just
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time ���로공 (
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 열사 days and
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time ������
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time  a tiny creature from outa
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 4-Shox'
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time ��the very concept of��
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 7 (1 episodes) ,
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time �� (as the say here
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time © Copywriting & Video
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time Ã± an evening as clear
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time ≒ The First
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time Nell​ & P
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time  the gods appeared: their great
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 7 students enbart from
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 5 and his dog (yes
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time  in Brooklet,Germ
===============================================
<s> Once upon a time ​it started small</s>
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 튻원동�
===============================================
<s>Once upon a time 09 : one shot special
===============================================
```